# Use of vhosts in AMQP

Tags: amqp

I'm new to AMQP and was wondering; What is the current usecase for the vhost part in the AMQ protocol?
The only information I can find is that you have to URL encode any forward slashes and that it used to be used for authorization, but that is now deprecated in the specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vhost` is used to have granular rights and plugins (some of them) management within single server or cluster. Typical use case is to have multiple projects that utilize AMQP service.

For more info you have to read broker-specific manual about `vhost`, but the idea is the same across all of them.

*Note, that `vhost` is not the same as virtual hosts in HTTP context.*